# 24Vdc signal for 800meters distance

Tags: 24v

what is the best/simple way to get a 24Vdc signal (with minimal loss) 
across 800 meters, without having to use an absurdly thick cable??

I am talking about a solenoid valve 24Vdc

and a proximity switch (Namur 8.2v nominal) it can operate between 5...25Vdc

@ plasmahh, you're saying thin cables, tell me which one then?? thank you :)

I got my answer, thanks to Neil_UK

Comment: What current? Also you say signal but then you say 24Vdc - you can't have both so state what precisely is the signal in terms of spectral content.

Comment: Phone companies used to use even longer thin cables for signals with similar voltages, so where is the problem?

Comment: Step-Up, then Step-Down. Losses are a function of the current, $I^2*R_cable$. So for the same power requirement if you step up the voltage before transmission, then step-down after, you will reduce your transmission losses. If this is just for signalling, then perhaps use a current loop.

Comment: If you are talking about microamperes or even a few tens of miliamperes then even 1mm² cable is enough *(Phone companies here in Turkey use very thin cables to carry 48VDC)*. But if you are talking about amperes then use either thicker cable *(what about heat on the cables?)* or step-up converter or an inverter.

Comment: You **MUST** specify the required power and/or current. Ideally, tell us what you are trying to actually do.

Comment: Is the signal discrete or continuous? What is the data rate or slew rate?

Answer (score 4):

800m of 1mm2 cable will have a resistance (there and back) of 27 ohms at 25C. If you short circuit the far end, you will get a little less than 1 Amp flowing from 24v.

Depending on the current you want to transmit, this may, or may not be, OK.

If your signal is 50mA or so, then you will get over 90% of your 24v at the far end.

If your signal is mA, then you could use thinner wires.

If you want to transmit several amps, and avoid wires thicker than 1mm2, then you could step up to a higher voltage for transmission, and step down again at the far end.

You need to do the resistance / voltage / current sums for your signal.

Comment: Do accept the answer if it helped you. I'm not sure whether that can be done with held questions though.